# AmazonsS3Client throws UnknownHostException if attempting to connect to a local service (MinIO)

Tags: java, amazon-s3, minio, testcontainers

In Short: Using `AmazonS3Client` to connect to a local instance of `MinIO` results in a `UnknownHostException` thrown because the url is resolved to `http://{bucket_name}.localhost:port`.

---

Detailed description of the problem:

I'm creating an integration test for a Java service that uses AmazonS3Client lib to retrieve content from S3. I'm using MinIO inside a test container to perform the role of Amazon S3, as follows:

```
@Container
static final GenericContainer<?> minioContainer = new GenericContainer<>("minio/minio:latest")
    .withCommand("server /data")
    .withEnv(
        Map.of(
            "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY", AWS_ACCESS_KEY.getValue(),
            "MINIO_SECRET_KEY", AWS_SECRET_KEY.getValue()
        )
    )
    .withExposedPorts(MINIO_PORT)
    .waitingFor(new HttpWaitStrategy()
        .forPath("/minio/health/ready")
        .forPort(MINIO_PORT)
        .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)));
```

and then I export its url dynamically (because test containers are deployed at a random port) using something like this:

```
String.format("http://%s:%s", minioContainer.getHost(), minioContainer.getFirstMappedPort())
```

which in turn results in a url like this:

```
http://localhost:54123
```

The problem I encountered during the runtime of my test lies within the actual implementation of `AmazonS3Client.getObject(String,String)` - when creating the request it performs the following validation (class `S3RequestEndpointResolver`, method `resolveRequestEndpoint`):

```
...    
if (shouldUseVirtualAddressing(endpoint)) {
        request.setEndpoint(convertToVirtualHostEndpoint(endpoint, bucketName));
        request.setResourcePath(SdkHttpUtils.urlEncode(getHostStyleResourcePath(), true));
    } else {
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setResourcePath(SdkHttpUtils.urlEncode(getPathStyleResourcePath(), true));
    }
}

private boolean shouldUseVirtualAddressing(final URI endpoint) {
    return !isPathStyleAccess && BucketNameUtils.isDNSBucketName(bucketName)
            && !isValidIpV4Address(endpoint.getHost());
}
```

This in turn returns `true` for the url `http://localhost:54123` and as a result this method

```
private static URI convertToVirtualHostEndpoint(URI endpoint, String bucketName) {
    try {
        return new URI(String.format("%s://%s.%s", endpoint.getScheme(), bucketName, endpoint.getAuthority()));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid bucket name: " + bucketName, e);
    }
}
```

concatenates the name of the bucket to the host resulting in: `http://mybucket.localhost:54123` and this ultimately results in a `UnknownHostException` to be thrown. I can work around this by setting the host to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`, but this is hardly a solution.

Therefore I was wondering if i) this a bug/limitation in `AmazonS3Client`?; ii) I'm the one who is missing something, e.g. poor configuration ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. Looking at the method used by the resolver:

```
private boolean shouldUseVirtualAddressing(final URI endpoint) {
    return !isPathStyleAccess && BucketNameUtils.isDNSBucketName(bucketName)
            && !isValidIpV4Address(endpoint.getHost());
}
```

which was returning true and leading the flow to the wrong concatenation I found that we can set the first variable `isPathStyleAccess` when building the client. In my case, I created a bean in my test configuration to override the main one:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {

    return AmazonS3Client.builder()
        .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true) //HERE
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
            new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY.getValue(), AWS_SECRET_KEY.getValue())
        ))
        .withEndpointConfiguration(
            new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(s3Endpoint, region)
        )
        .build();
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the SDK V2, the solution was pretty similar:

```java
S3AsyncClient s3 = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                .forcePathStyle(true) // adding this one
                .endpointOverride(new URI(s3Endpoint))
                .credentialsProvider(() -> AwsBasicCredentials.create(s3Properties.getAccessKey(), s3Properties.getSecretKey()))
                .build()
```